# How can i use JQuery to redirect and open a new window at the same time?

Tags: jquery, redirect, hyperlink, window

I'm working a page where a user has two buttons. one button simply redirects them to a home page, the other button not only redirects them to the home page, but also opens a new window/tab to a different link.

```
     <button class="return" type="button">
        <?= $html->image('cross.gif') ?> Return
      </button>
      <button class="walletcards" type="button">
        <?= $html->image('cross.gif') ?> Print Wallet Cards
      </button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function() {
         $('button.return').click( function() {
         $(window.location).attr('href','/accounts/view/<?=$data['Email']  ['acctgrpid'];   ?>');
});

$('button.walletcards').click(function(){
 $(location).attr('href', '/accounts/view/<?=$data['Email']['acctgrpid']; ?>')
 });

 $('button.walletcards').click(function(){
  window.close();
  window.open('/wallet_cards/account/<?=$data['Email']['acctgrpid']; ?>');
  });
```

Now my issue this works, but it opens two windows/tabs for the link ("/wallet_cards/account....) how do i stop it from opening two windows/tabs, or is there a better way i can do this.

Comment: why do you have 2 event handlers for button click.. integrate them into one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little confusing in what it is doing versus what you described.  It would appear that what your code is doing is adding 2 click events to the button, one that redirects to accounts, and one that closes the window and opens a new one to wallet_cards/account.

Also your window.close() comes before your window.open()...I would reverse those to prevent problems there.

So I would update to something like:

```
$('button.walletcards').click(function() {
    window.open('/wallet_cards/account/<?=$data['Email']['acctgrpid']; ?>');
    window.location.href = '/wallet_cards/account/<?=$data['Email']['acctgrpid']; ?>';
    //window.close();  // Not sure why you are redirecting but then closing the window...
});
```

Comment: You probably meant `window.location.href = '/wallet_cards/account/<?=$data['Email']['acctgrpid']; ?>';`

Comment: Yes, thank you! Updated the code appropriately.  Too used to using jquery for everything...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to put this 2 actions in the same function?

```
$('button.walletcards').click(function(){
  window.close();
  window.open('/wallet_cards/account/<?=$data['Email']['acctgrpid']; ?>');

 $(location).attr('href', '/accounts/view/<?=$data['Email']['acctgrpid']; ?>')
 });
```

Comment: I'd invert the order of `open` and `close` method calls, also would not use jQuery to assign a value to `location.href` as this is already available on `window`