# Redirect user on homepage after clicking a 'a href'

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

My question is:
I have my website page *homedomain.com*

And I have a link on page with article :

```
<a href='https://anotherurl.com' target='_blank'>Link</a>
```

This link will be opened in a **new** tab.
I need to redirect user on a old tab (where the article with link is located) to the homepage *homedomain.com*

*Do you have any ideas how to do this?*

Here is an example of what I need. Try to click on any link.
https://smartinvestorsdaily.com/crazy-new-revelation-from-elon-musk-wow/

Comment: You can use `window.open()` and `window.location.href` in a click event handler

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536371/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-redirect-and-open-a-new-window-at-the-same-time

Comment: This works
thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536371/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-redirect-and-open-a-new-window-at-the-same-time